# display item selected from recycleview in label kivy

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy

i want to print the value selected from my list in to label but when i clicked in this list i have a message error :
`selected = self.ids.op_selected File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

this my py

```
class RVItem(Factory.Button):
    def get_data_index(self):

        return self.parent.get_view_index_at(self.center)
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.get_data_index())
        selected = self.ids.op_selected
        selected.text = self.text

class SecondWindow(BoxLayout, Screen):
    myresult = ListProperty([("liste_des_operations_id","PART_NO","Operation__NO","OPERATION_DESCRIPTION")])

    def insert_part(self):
        partnum = self.ids.Part_field
        part = partnum.text

        mycursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM liste_des_operations WHERE PART_NO = %s",
            (part,))
        self.myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

kv

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

        RecycleView:
            id: list_des_operation
            data: [{'text':"{}".format(OPERATION_DESCRIPTION)} for liste_des_operations_id,PART_NO,Operation__NO,OPERATION_DESCRIPTION in root.myresult]
            viewclass: "RVItem"
            text_selected: ""
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                orientation: "vertical"
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                key_selection: 'selectable'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True


        Label:
            id: op_selected
            text: "op"
```

Comment: The `op_selected` is not an `id` in the `RVItem`. That causes the error you are seeing.

Comment: You need to post more of your `kv` to show the root element that contains`op_selected`. That root element is the one that must be used to access the `id` of  `op_selected`.